# Use number of characters in a cell as Excel formula criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns in a spreadsheet, and my goal is to combine the individual references (column B) where the customer is the same (column A) - but only up to a maximum of 20 characters.

In column E, I use the following formula to combine the references if the value in column A is the same as the cell above:
=IF(A2<>A1,"Reference " & B2,E1 & " " & B2)

In column G, I use the following formula to only return the final concatenated value:
=IF(A2<>A3,CONCATENATE("",E2,""),"")

However, I'm struggling to find a way to stop combining the references if the cell length contains more than 20 characters, and starting a new concatenation on the next line - like I've put in column I?

Thanks!

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: Given the first three columns, you could do this in Power Query.  But what happens if references are of such a length that you require four or more rows to meet your 20 character limit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not looking for a parsimonious spreadsheet. Thus, this is what I can think of:

Next to column G, you may add this formula, **beginning on row 2**:

```
=IF(LEN(G3)>20,IF(LEN(E2)>20,"",E2),IF(G2="","","Reference "&B2))
```

Column H (or I, as you wish) will have a 3-step IF statement:

1. If the length of the FOLLOWING string on column G is greater than 20, then copy the value on E2;
2. But, if the value on E2 is longer than 20 characters, then return an empty cell;
3. Finally, if G3 has less than 20 characters AND provided G2 is NOT empty, then return "Reference" + whatever value is on B2. If G2 is empty, then return an empty cell ("").

Thanks to the person who brought the image into the answer. I had to refresh it and that made it unavailable again, shamefully.

[This is what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gnu.png)

Comment: Hi Oscar. Thank you for this. I've now added this code and it gets me close - but it's not quite there. If you take a look at cell I12 of your view, where it contains "Reference Ref 10 Ref11", this is still over 20 characters - as the formula takes the value from the previous row in column E, even if this is over the 20 character limit. This gives me something to work on though. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this reply before. I just edited the answer. Perhaps it is a bit late now, but maybe it will help someone in the future.